# Installing virtualbox on Debian: dependency problems

Tags: debian, apt, virtualbox, dependencies

I'm currently running Debian Wheezy (Testing). I want to install `virtualbox` but when I run the following:

```
# aptitude install virtualbox
```

...I get the following result:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt4-qt3support : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-6 is to be installed.
                     Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-6 is to be installed.
 qdbus : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-6 is to be installed.
 libqt4-script : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-6 is to be installed.
 libqt4-designer : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-6 is to be installed.
                   Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-6 is to be installed.
 libqt4-network : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-6 is to be installed.
 libqt4-dbus : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-6 is to be installed.
 qt4-qtconfig : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-6 is to be installed.
                Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-6 is to be installed.
 libqt4-sql : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-6 is to be installed.
 libqt4-xml : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-6 is to be installed.
 libqt4-sql-mysql : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-6 is to be installed.
```

Aptitude then gives me a list of solutions, none of which seem very appealing. It seems to want to install packages from unstable rather than testing, but I don't really want to do this.
**Why is this a problem if the packages have the correct version numbers?**

This is the contents of my `/etc/apt/source.list`:

```
deb http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/ wheezy main non-free contrib
deb-src http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/ wheezy main non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free

# The following line is required for iceweasel in wheezy
deb http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian experimental main

# The following line is required for icedove in wheezy
deb http://debian.man.ac.uk/debian unstable main
```

Comment: the packages do NOT have the correct numbers? you have ....-2, the version you try to install needs ....-6 . Try to install a lower version or edit your sources.list to only fetch non-unstable releases.

Comment: Run apt-get update again.

Comment: Hm do you have pinning otherwise you are not running wheezy but sid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ulrich Dangel's [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59930/installing-virtualbox-on-debian-dependency-problems#comment82885_59930) was correct. I had the repos specified in `sources.list` but hadn't set up pinning correctly, so I had conflicting packages being pulled from unstable that I didn't want.

[This blog](http://danielsokolowski.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/installing-debian-unstable-safely-with.html) helped me configure the pinning correctly and now `virtualbox` installs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the version conflict with repo you have used for virtualbox.

You can better use the repo provided by the virtualbox in their official  [download](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) link.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent a lot of time sloving this issue and finally. This worked!
First download this file
[Depency File](https://app.box.com/s/z9ttqf4itt5oa729km3c3vz3sivr930q)
Extract it, you will see debs file on that folder. Open terminal cd to that folder and run dpkg -i *.deb
After that you can normally install VirtualBox.

Comment: This answer does not make clear who made that file, or what exactly is in it, or if anybody should even trust it. Also, once the file goes down, this answer becomes useless as it does not explain what's in it, what assumptions underly it, or how to adapt it to a changed situation.

Answer (score -1):

`sudo apt-get install -f` followed by `sudo apt-get install virtualbox`